# Preparing for OCR OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

I am making an application that uses OCR and I am using OpenCV to threshold the image to improve the OCR results, I have gotten pretty good results but I want to know if anyone has any suggestions for improvement.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
// Convert to grayscale.
cv::cvtColor(cvMat, cvMat, CV_RGB2GRAY);
// Apply adaptive threshold.
cv::adaptiveThreshold(cvMat, cvMat, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY, 3, 5);
// Attempt to sharpen the image.
cv::GaussianBlur(cvMat, cvMat, cv::Size(0, 0), 3);
cv::addWeighted(cvMat, 1.5, cvMat, -0.5, 0, cvMat);
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions to improve results, thanks.

Sample Images:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Please post at least one sample image. As a general rule, image processing applications are best addressed when you post exemplary images. There are so many scenarios in which text can appear that it's not sufficient to simply look at a few lines of code in a library and judge what you should do next.

Comment: Added sample images. I plan to add a camera overlay on iOS to remove needing edge detection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best algorithms for thresholding problem in the OCR field is sauvola method.You can use the below code.

```
#ifndef _THRESHOLDER
#define _THRESHOLDER
#include <cv.h>
#include "type.h"
using namespace cv;

enum class BhThresholdMethod{OTSU,NIBLACK,SAUVOLA,WOLFJOLION};


class BhThresholder
{
public :
    void doThreshold(InputArray src ,OutputArray dst,const BhThresholdMethod &method);
private:
};

#endif //_THRESHOLDER
thresholder.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"

#define uget(x,y)    at<unsigned char>(y,x)
#define uset(x,y,v)  at<unsigned char>(y,x)=v;
#define fget(x,y)    at<float>(y,x)
#define fset(x,y,v)  at<float>(y,x)=v;

// *************************************************************
// glide a window across the image and
// create two maps: mean and standard deviation.
// *************************************************************
//#define BINARIZEWOLF_VERSION  "2.3 (February 26th, 2013)"


double calcLocalStats (Mat &im, Mat &map_m, Mat &map_s, int win_x, int win_y) {

    double m,s,max_s, sum, sum_sq, foo;
    int wxh = win_x / 2;
    int wyh = win_y / 2;
    int x_firstth = wxh;
    int y_lastth = im.rows-wyh-1;
    int y_firstth= wyh;
    double winarea = win_x*win_y;

    max_s = 0;
    for (int j = y_firstth ; j<=y_lastth; j++) 
    {
        // Calculate the initial window at the beginning of the line
        sum = sum_sq = 0;
        for (int wy=0 ; wy<win_y; wy++)
            for (int wx=0 ; wx<win_x; wx++) {
                foo = im.uget(wx,j-wyh+wy);
                sum    += foo;
                sum_sq += foo*foo;
            }
        m  = sum / winarea;
        s  = sqrt ((sum_sq - (sum*sum)/winarea)/winarea);
        if (s > max_s)
            max_s = s;
        map_m.fset(x_firstth, j, m);
        map_s.fset(x_firstth, j, s);

        // Shift the window, add and remove new/old values to the histogram
        for (int i=1 ; i <= im.cols  -win_x; i++) {

            // Remove the left old column and add the right new column
            for (int wy=0; wy<win_y; ++wy) {
                foo = im.uget(i-1,j-wyh+wy);
                sum    -= foo;
                sum_sq -= foo*foo;
                foo = im.uget(i+win_x-1,j-wyh+wy);
                sum    += foo;
                sum_sq += foo*foo;
            }
            m  = sum / winarea;
            s  = sqrt ((sum_sq - (sum*sum)/winarea)/winarea);
            if (s > max_s)
                max_s = s;
            map_m.fset(i+wxh, j, m);
            map_s.fset(i+wxh, j, s);
        }
    }

    return max_s;
}




void NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion (InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst,const BhThresholdMethod &version,int winx, int winy, double k, double dR) {

    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    Mat dst = _dst.getMat();
    double m, s, max_s;
    double th=0;
    double min_I, max_I;
    int wxh = winx/2;
    int wyh = winy/2;
    int x_firstth= wxh;
    int x_lastth = src.cols-wxh-1;
    int y_lastth = src.rows-wyh-1;
    int y_firstth= wyh;
    int mx, my;

    // Create local statistics and store them in a double matrices
    Mat map_m = Mat::zeros (src.size(), CV_32FC1);
    Mat map_s = Mat::zeros (src.size(), CV_32FC1);
    max_s = calcLocalStats (src, map_m, map_s, winx, winy);

    minMaxLoc(src, &min_I, &max_I);

    Mat thsurf (src.size(), CV_32FC1);

    // Create the threshold surface, including border processing
    // ----------------------------------------------------

    for (int j = y_firstth ; j<=y_lastth; j++) {

        // NORMAL, NON-BORDER AREA IN THE MIDDLE OF THE WINDOW:
        for (int i=0 ; i <= src.cols-winx; i++) {

            m  = map_m.fget(i+wxh, j);
            s  = map_s.fget(i+wxh, j);

            // Calculate the threshold
            switch (version) {

            case BhThresholdMethod::NIBLACK:
                    th = m + k*s;
                    break;

            case BhThresholdMethod::SAUVOLA:
                    th = m * (1 + k*(s/dR-1));
                    break;

            case BhThresholdMethod::WOLFJOLION:
                    th = m + k * (s/max_s-1) * (m-min_I);
                    break;

                default:
                    cerr << "Unknown threshold type in ImageThresholder::surfaceNiblackImproved()\n";
                    exit (1);
            }

            thsurf.fset(i+wxh,j,th);

            if (i==0) {
                // LEFT BORDER
                for (int i=0; i<=x_firstth; ++i)
                    thsurf.fset(i,j,th);

                // LEFT-UPPER CORNER
                if (j==y_firstth)
                    for (int u=0; u<y_firstth; ++u)
                    for (int i=0; i<=x_firstth; ++i)
                        thsurf.fset(i,u,th);

                // LEFT-LOWER CORNER
                if (j==y_lastth)
                    for (int u=y_lastth+1; u<src.rows; ++u)
                    for (int i=0; i<=x_firstth; ++i)
                        thsurf.fset(i,u,th);
            }

            // UPPER BORDER
            if (j==y_firstth)
                for (int u=0; u<y_firstth; ++u)
                    thsurf.fset(i+wxh,u,th);

            // LOWER BORDER
            if (j==y_lastth)
                for (int u=y_lastth+1; u<src.rows; ++u)
                    thsurf.fset(i+wxh,u,th);
        }

        // RIGHT BORDER
        for (int i=x_lastth; i<src.cols; ++i)
            thsurf.fset(i,j,th);

        // RIGHT-UPPER CORNER
        if (j==y_firstth)
            for (int u=0; u<y_firstth; ++u)
            for (int i=x_lastth; i<src.cols; ++i)
                thsurf.fset(i,u,th);

        // RIGHT-LOWER CORNER
        if (j==y_lastth)
            for (int u=y_lastth+1; u<src.rows; ++u)
            for (int i=x_lastth; i<src.cols; ++i)
                thsurf.fset(i,u,th);
    }
    cerr << "surface created" << endl;


    for (int y=0; y<src.rows; ++y) 
    for (int x=0; x<src.cols; ++x) 
    {
        if (src.uget(x,y) >= thsurf.fget(x,y))
        {
            dst.uset(x,y,255);
        }
        else
        {
            dst.uset(x,y,0);
        }
    }
}

void BhThresholder::doThreshold(InputArray _src ,OutputArray _dst,const BhThresholdMethod &method)
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat();

    int winx = 0;
    int winy = 0;
    float optK=0.5;
    if (winx==0 || winy==0) {
        winy = (int) (2.0 * src.rows - 1)/3;
        winx = (int) src.cols-1 < winy ? src.cols-1 : winy;

        // if the window is too big, than we asume that the image
        // is not a single text box, but a document page: set
        // the window size to a fixed constant.
        if (winx > 100)
            winx = winy = 40;
    }

    // Threshold
    _dst.create(src.size(), CV_8UC1);
    Mat dst = _dst.getMat();

    //medianBlur(src,dst,5);
    GaussianBlur(src,dst,Size(5,5),0);
//#define _BH_SHOW_IMAGE
#ifdef _BH_DEBUG
    #define _BH_SHOW_IMAGE
#endif
    //medianBlur(src,dst,7);
    switch (method)
    {
    case BhThresholdMethod::OTSU :
        threshold(dst,dst,128,255,CV_THRESH_OTSU);
        break;
    case BhThresholdMethod::SAUVOLA :
    case BhThresholdMethod::WOLFJOLION :
        NiblackSauvolaWolfJolion (src, dst, method, winx, winy, optK, 128);


    }

    bitwise_not(dst,dst);


#ifdef _BH_SHOW_IMAGE

#undef _BH_SHOW_IMAGE
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is comparsion table for thresholding methods: http://clweb.csa.iisc.ernet.in/rahulsharma/binarize/set1.php?id=set1%2Fimage00b

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- Since you're starting with a rectangular object that may be viewed at a non-normal angle, use an affine transform to warp the image so that it appears rectangular with right angle corners.
- Before the affine transform, you should probably remove barrel distortion (the curviness of the card edges).
- Consider using an adaptive threshold rather than a simple global binarization threshold.
- If you can find a proper OCR algorithm that doesn't require binary images, use that. Although binarization will work well for black text on a white background, in general binarization presents a lot of problems if you want to achieve high accuracy (i.e., character recognition approaching 98%+ for arbitrary strings of characters)
- Try to sample with better resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I believe I am performing an adaptive threshold above, but I will try out the other suggestions and get back to you.